# Load Updated Image Using Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-imaging-library

I am making a basic Mandelbrot zoom program using pygame that uses pillow to generate images each time a user zooms in.  When this image is updated the pygame window simply loads the original image and not the updated one.

My current solution is to kill the pygame window with each zoom and reinitialize it which adds a fair amount of time to each zoom.  Here is my current code

```py
def pg_window(width, height):
    pg.init()

    fill_color = 255, 255, 255
    window = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))

    global set_image
    set_img = pg.image.load('mandelbrot.png')
    # The original load of the image
    zoom_x = int(width * .15)
    zoom_y = int(height * .15)

    while True:
        window.fill(fill_color)

        ... extra code ommitted ...

        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                zoom(*zoom_rect.center, width, height, zoom_x, zoom_y)
                # The zoom function call modifies the image directly.
                set_image = pg.image.load('mandelbrot.png')
                # changing the set_image variable just loads the original image, not the updated one
                # My current solution involves calling pg.quit() here
                # and recalling the pg_window function to reinitialize

        window.fill(fill_color)
        window.blit(set_img, (0, 0))
        pg.display.flip()
```

Is there anyway to load an updated image without resetting the window?

Comment: How do you draw the image to the window? This is not enough code to answer your question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Rabbid76 My apologies, I've edited my post to show how I load the image now.

Comment: This is still not a minimal example. How are you updating ```set_img```?

Comment: The image is directly modified by pillow (each pixel is changed), so essentially the only thing that remains the same after the image is updated is the name (mandelbrot.png)

Comment: @EthanPeck Why do you not reload the image `set_image = pg.image.load('mandelbrot.png')`?

Comment: @EthanPeck Do you want to reload the image image in a function. You've to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) to write to a variable in global namespace from a function. `global set_image`

Comment: I am trying to reload the image by calling ```set_image = pg.image.load('mandelbrot.png')``` again.  This is done within the same function.

Comment: @EthanPeck You've to show more code. especially the part where the images  is (re)loaded

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have now included the majority of m pg_window function.  I omitted some unrelated code.

Comment: @EthanPeck The name of the image which is`blit` to the `window` is `set_img` rather than `set_image`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the image which is `blit` to the window is `set_img` rather than `set_image`.
So you've to set `set_img`:

```py
while True:
    window.fill(fill_color)

    # [...]

    for event in pg.event.get():

        # [...]

        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            # [...]

            set_img = pg.image.load('mandelbrot.png') # <--- set_img 


        window.fill(fill_color)
        window.blit(set_img, (0, 0))
        pg.display.flip()
```